# How do I call a matrix index which is within a list for numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I want to call out the 2nd row 3rd column [number 10] of the matrix from the list of A(3) from the code below.

```
Mlist = []
z = 10
while z > 0:
A = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,28],
    [9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
    ])
z -= 1 
Mlist.append(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Mlist[n][i,j]
```

where `n` is the index of the matrix in the list and `i` and `j` are the position in the matrix.